# Jquery mouseover animate with get function

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm making separate posts, I want the posts to load automatically without page refresh so I'm using jquery `$.get` . Next if anyone moves mouse over that post a div will animate from left. But since the posts refresh every 30 seconds the mouse animation doesn't work & the div just blinks & hides, doesn't stays. What's the better way?

Here's my code -Jquery

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sharePosts").hide();
    $(".LrgPosts").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find(".sharePosts").show().animate({width: '51px'}, "fast");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find(".sharePosts").hide().animate({width: '0px'}, "slow");
    });

    $(function() {
        refreshEPosts();
    });

    function refreshEPosts(){
        setTimeout(refreshEPosts,30000);
        $.get('getNewPosts.php', function(data) {
            $('#leftAlign').html(data).fadeIn();    
        });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are replacing the entire HTML, the show and hide animation of your div is just blinking and not staying. I think you should just keep adding the new posts to the HTML dom instead of completely replacing the HTML.

```
 // this is just and example, you cant modify with your own code.  

 function refreshEPosts(){
    setTimeout(refreshEPosts,30000);
    $.get('getNewPosts.php', function(data) {

        if(gotNewPost(data)){
            var newPostHtml = "<div>" + data + "</div>";
            $('#leftAlign').append(newPostHtml ).fadeIn();
        } 

    });
 }
```

Comment: it infinitely keep fetching all posts

Comment: You already have your posts in your HTML dom, just keep checking for the updates, if you find a new post, create HTML for that post and append or prepend that post to your posts div.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you want to do is use the `.on()` function to attach the event.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.Lrgposts',function(){ // stuff});
```

Use the same for mouseleave. One problem with `.mouseenter()` or `.mouseleave()` is it doesn't work for dynamic HTML.